# Why not to mix dev and production deployment into a single web app on azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Would there be any issue to create 4 deployment slots on Azure web app,

```
AzureWebApp1 
--- Dev slot 
--- Staging slot 
--- Pre-Prod slot 
--- Prod slot
```

Someone stated that it's better to have like this,

```
AzureWebApp-Prod 
--- Pre-Prod slot 
--- Prod slot

AzureWebApp-Dev 
--- Dev slot 
--- Staging slot
```

They were not able to explain why and I am not sure which approach is best, and there is no mention of this on MSDN as far as I searched on guide here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/environments?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to run both production and development in same web app. Because the resources allocated by azure app service will distribute among all deployment slot. This may effect to the production web app.

As of best practice divide both production & development in to two different app service plan.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots